# Using TFS Proxy Server As Offline TFS Server

Tags: asp.net, .net, tfs

So here is my situation.  I have a laptop that I want to be able to do mobile development on.  If I have to travel for a week or so I still want to be able to use TFS, however I may not be able to access my main server.  I mainly code in C# .NET running Windows 7.  The TFS Proxy would be on a VM running Server 2008 R2 that I would spin up while on the road.

Is it feasible to use TFS Proxy as an offline solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it only caches files (get) and only the files that have been 'get' before through this proxy server. For things like the history, check out or checkin in you need the real TFS server. It also does not cache work items.

PS: There is TFS Offline mode. [Here](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2009/04/14/working-offline-with-team-foundation-server.aspx) is an old description.

**EDIT**

It seems the next TFS version will support this offline scenario much better. Read more about it [here](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2011/08/02/version-control-model-enhancements-in-tfs-11.aspx?PageIndex=3#comments).

Comment: You could always have a local TFS server on your laptop

Comment: So how would that work out, I have considered this.  Wouldn't it mess up the project bindings though?  Essentially I would check my mobile changes into my laptop TFS and then when I get home just check all the changes in at once to my main TFS server?

Comment: Yes I guess would mess up the project's tfs bindings. I have no experience on that subject. Maybe you should ask a new question on that subject. I believe this one is answered.

Comment: I'm just going to deal with it ;) I have been coding without TFS for a week or two now it feels like I'm coding 'naked' - just like the good old days.  I marked this as the answer thanks for your help.